# copying one Array value to another array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 array of `object`. 1st array of object have property which I want to copy to other array.

1st array of object

```
HotelRoomResponse[] hr=new HotelRoomResponse[100];
```

2nd array of object

```
RateInfos[] rt = new RateInfos[100];
```

now what i want to do is copy a property of 1st array like

```
rt=hr[].RateInfo;
```

but it give error. What is correct way to do this????

Comment: How does RateInfos relate to HotelRoomResponse

Comment: want moar equal answerz!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RateInfos[] rt = hr.Select(item => item.RateInfo).ToArray();
```

Comment: @DeepakRaghav: Do you understand *how* it's working though? Have you used LINQ? It's worth doing some reading to make sure you know what's going on here.

Comment: yeah i used LINQ.Not much but enough to understand the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can't just project an array like that. You effectively have to loop - although you don't need to do that manually in your own code. LINQ makes it very easy, for example:

```
RateInfos[] rt = hr.Select(x => x.RateInfo).ToArray();
```

Or you could use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
RateInfos[] rt = Array.ConvertAll(hr, x => x.RateInfo);
```

In both of these cases there's still a loop somewhere - it's just not in your code.

If you're quite new to C# and don't understand LINQ, lambda expressions, delegates etc yet, then you *could* just write the code yourself:

```
RateInfos[] rt = new RateInfos[hr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < rt.Length; i++)
{
    rt[i] = hr[i].RateInfo;
}
```

All of these three will achieve the same result.

- The first approach is probably the most idiomatic in modern C#. It will work with any input type, and you can change from `ToArray()` to `ToList()` to get a `List<RateInfos>` instead of an array, etc.
- The second approach is slightly more efficient than the first and will work with .NET 2.0 (whereas LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5) - you'll still need a C# 3 compiler or higher though. It will only work as written with arrays, but there's a similar `ConvertAll` method for `List<T>`.
- The third approach is the most efficient, but obviously more code as well. It's simpler for a newcomer to understand, but doesn't express what you're trying to achieve as clearly when you know how all the language features work for the first two solutions.

Comment: +1 for `Array.ConvertAll`. See your `you'll still need a C# 3 compiler` note

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: It's .NET 2.0 compatible. It was introduced in C# 3 (there's no such thing as C# 3.5), but you can still use it when targeting .NET 2.0. I chose the wording in my answer carefully :)

Comment: `there's no such thing as C# 3.5` sure, I've meant **.net 3.5**. Anyway, marvelous answer, as usual.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Right - but the key is that lambda expressions are a C# feature, not a .NET library or CLR feature. That's why it's crucial to separate language versions from CLR or library versions :)

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ:

```
RateInfos[] rt = hr.Select(x => x.RateInfo).ToArray();
```